# Encapsulating a custom haskell type with all operations into one class

Tags: c++, haskell, custom-data-type

If I wanted to create a new type in C++, in which I overload a bunch of operators I can do something like:

```
class Stringy {
    public:
    explict Stringy(const char *buffer){}
    friend Stringy operator + (const Stringy &s1, const Stringy &s2) { ... }
    friend Stringy operator - (const Stringy &s1, const Stringy &s2) { ... }
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream &oss, const String& s1) { ... }
};
```

Now If I attempt to do the same in Haskell, I find myself doing (an example):

```hs
data Stringy = Stringy([Char])
-- do something unrelated here --
(+) :: Stringy -> Stringy -> Stringy
(-) :: Stringy -> Stringy -> Stringy
(removeDups) :: Stringy -> Stringy
-- do something else unrelated here --
(>>) :: Stringy -> IO --(is IO right?)
```

My point is that the c++ one looks more put together because everything you do within that class relates in some way to the class. On the other hand it is possible for the operator declarations for the haskell one to be all over the place and not required to be together. If someone takes a look at the c++ code, they can immediately identify which operations are part of the class and the ones that aren't. How would I achieve this same uniformity in Haskell?

I'm still a beginner in Haskell, so please just use the simple way of doing things. Thanks

Comment: If you want to know all of the ways a type can be used in one place, [haddock](https://www.haskell.org/haddock/) does a good job of generating this documentation. For example, if you look at the documentation for the [`Proxy`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.1.4/docs/Pipes-Core.html#t:Proxy) from pipes you can see in the **Instances** section that a `Proxy` can be used in a lot of different ways outside of the functions with new names defined just for proxies. The functions that operate on a type, and came with the type, will usually be in a *namespace* devoted to that type.

Comment: What about to put all `Stringy`'s stuff into the module `Stringy.sh`?

Comment: @wowofbob, is that the equivalent of `.h` files in c++? If so thanks I will look into that at a later time but I don't think having multiple files will solve the problem

Comment: I think the question is ill-formed. What does it mean for an operation to be "related in some way to a type"? What should be done with operations like parsing a `Stringy` into a `ParseTree` that are related to many types (and therefore can't sensibly be put in one class or the other without apparently being "unrelated" to the other class)? What about polymorphism? That said, good library designers do try to put related functionality together -- grouped into modules, and often even lexically nearby -- they just have great flexibility to choose what that means and how the code is organized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel said, good library designers do try to put related functionality into the same module. So typically the typeclass `Stringy`, and all of the "basic" operations on `Stringy`s would be in the module `Stringy` (or `X.Y.Z.Stringy`), in the file `Stringy.hs`.

Eventually, I think you will come to appreciate the flexibility that Haskell gives you.
For example, suppose you want to define a function with the type

```
myfunction :: Stringy -> Thingy -> Doohicky
```

This doesn't really fit into any of the three typeclasses (`Stringy`, `Thingy`, or `Doohicky`), because it references types that aren't part of the typeclass.
Perhaps those three typeclasses are in three separate modules, written long ago by different people.
You are the first person to realise that `myFunction` would be a useful operation.
Haskell allows you to put this function wherever you think it makes the most sense.
You might create a whole new module devoted to ways of producing `Doohicky`s from combinations of values of other typeclasses.